# How to change the output of json to match converted formatting in python

Tags: python, json

The source code for the json is from a json file that contains output as shown below

```
 [{
    "text": "text to be shown",
    "label": [
        {
            "text": "text to be shown",
            "purpose": "scoping",
            "starting": 13,
            "ending": 20
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to remove or ignore the name of the keys within the label attribute, but retain the value within it. So that the final output will read as below

```
[{
    "text": "text to be shown",
    "label": [["text to be shown","scoping",13,20]]
}]
```

Comment: you can convert a dcitionary `dic` to a list of its values with `list(dic.values())`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using this code 
`with open('data.json') as data:
  json_dict = json.load(data)

  print([d["label"] for d in json_dict])`

but this only removes the label and doesnt edit out the values within the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the json file is saved as 'data.json' and is within the same folder as your script, do:

```
#run this in python3
import json


with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

data[0]['label'][0] = list(data[0]['label'][0].values())
print(data)
```

You should see:

```
[{'text': 'text to be shown', 'label': [['text to be shown', 'scoping', 13, 20]]}]
```

Why this works: Remember that lists are mutable. Thus you can reassign the list contents in its place and the modifications will be reflected within the same object.

Cheers!

Comment: This works for only one part of it, what if there are multiple files within the json file ?

Comment: If the format is different in the other files then you have to drill down and see the common elements between those files and leverage the logic I showed above to re-construct the desired output. The answer I gave was for your particular question and it should help understand how to tackle the problem moving forward.
PS: Feel free to accept it as the correct answers if I answered is what you asked :)

Comment: Np. Good luck! :)